# how to show ros marker in python?

Tags: python, ros, rospy

I want to show a 3D `bbox` in ROS with Python. I have the 3d `bbox` coordinates, and I want to use a marker to show. However, I added some points which were the corner coordinate to the marker and published them, but I didn't see the `bbox`, what's wrong with my code?

Here is my code:

```
markers = MarkerArray()        
for i in range(len(self.bbox_data)):
     marker = Marker(type=Marker.LINE_LIST,ns='velodyne', action=Marker.ADD)
     marker.header.frame_id = "velodyne"
     marker.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
     if self.bbox_data[i][0][0] == frame:

     for n in range(8):
         point = geom_msg.Point(self.bbox_data[i][n+1][0],self.bbox_data[i][n+1][1],self.bbox_data[i][n+1][1])
         marker.points.append(point)

     marker.scale.x = 0.02
     marker.lifetime = rospy.Duration.from_sec(0.1)
     marker.color.a = 1.0
     marker.color.r = 0.5
     marker.color.g = 0.5 
     marker.color.b = 0.5    
     markers.markers.append(marker)

self.bbox.publish(markers)
```

where

```
(self.bbox_data[i][n+1][0],self.bbox_data[i][n+1][1],self.bbox_data[i][n+1][2])
```

is

```
(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> but I didn't see the bbox

what exactly do you mean? Do you see nothing at all or just a couple of parallel lines or something else?

There is one small bug in your code creating the point message. You're adding the `x, y, y` values instead of x, y, z.

However you're also not creating a set of lines describing the bounding box correctly. The bbox_data appears to list the 8 corner points of the bounding box, you need to define the 12 edge lines connecting these points so they're drawn in RVIZ. The [line_list marker](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker#Line_List_.28LINE_LIST.3D5.29) needs two points to define each line, since There is no simple algorithm to match the 8 points to the 24 start and end points you need to add to the marker msg, so you may have to hard code that part.

These two bugs may well be combining in such a way that you don't see anything on screen, but hopefully this will help you fix it.